# Which CSS component to edit on a Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a site at: http://www.learnerator.com/admissions-essays/

I want to use the WP editor to change the line height of the categories in the right sidebar because I think there is too much vertical spacing, but for the life of me I can not find which CSS definition to edit. I have figured out how to edit the font size, but not the line height.

But Everything I have tried to change line height, padding, and margin for li {} and the native classes used by the theme have not worked.

The specific list items have a class called "cat-item" but it is not in the style.css file for the theme. When I manually add it through the editor and play around with the margin, padding, and line-height, nothing happens.

Anyone have any ideas? The theme I am using is called Farad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 890:
    .widget ul li, .widget ol li {

Change the margin